# How to make the target of an output link be displayed next to the pageblocktable?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, custom-controller, pageblocksection, apexpage

So I'm having an issue trying to display the contacts of accounts next to the pageblocktable. The functionality I want to occur is that once an account is clicked to display the contacts for that account next to the pageblocktable.

```
<apex:page controller="FirstController" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="First Apex Page"></apex:sectionHeader>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="" id="pageBlock">
           <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton value="View" action="{!ViewData}" id="theButton" rerender="pageBlock"></apex:commandButton>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
            <apex:tabPanel switchType="Client" selectedTab="Home" id="theTabPanel" >
            <apex:tab label="Home" name="Home" id="tabOne">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(accounts))}">
                <apex:pageBlockSection id="contactDisplay" rendered="True">{!a.Contacts}</apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">   
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Account Name{!IF(sortExpression=='name',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdSort">
                            <apex:param value="name" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!a.Id}" target="contactDisplay" >{!a.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Rating}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Rating{!IF(sortExpression=='Rating',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                            <apex:param value="Rating" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Industry}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Industry City{!IF(sortExpression=='Industry',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                            <apex:param value="Industry" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:tab>
            <apex:tab label="Account" name="Account" id="tabTwo"></apex:tab>
            <apex:tab label="Contact" name="Contact" id="tabThree"></apex:tab>
            </apex:tabPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My approach is setting up pageblocksection and giving it an Id which I will reference in the output link I don't know if this is viable also if it is would it be declared inside the pageblock or outside the pageblock? 
Also I know I can't query the contacts to be displayed in visualforce pages would I need to do that in my Controller?

Answer (score 0):

I see a skeleton of the approach here:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="contactDisplay" rendered="True">{!a.Contacts}    
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

followed by

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!a.Id}" target="contactDisplay" >
{!a.Name}
</apex:outputLink>
```

That will not work, but it's headed towards the right direction.

What you'll need to do here is three things:

1. You need to set the selected Account in your controller when the user clicks to choose an Account.
2. You need, in your controller, to query and provide access to the Contacts for that Account.
3. You need your page to re-render the Contacts view to show the new data.

There are number of ways to do this in Visualforce. A simple approach to get started with would be to use an [`<apex:commandLink>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandLink.htm) component with an [`<apex:param>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm) to set the Id of the selected Account in a controller member variable.

The `action` attribute of the `<apex:commandLink>` would point to a controller action that would query the Contacts associated with the selected Account and populate them in an instance variable.

Your `commandLink` would have a `rerender` attribute with the Id of the page region containing Contacts. When the server action completes, that area will then be re-rendered to show the new data.

You'd end up with something like

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!selectAccount}" value="Save" id="theCommandLink" rerender="contactDisplay">
    <apex:param name="id" value="{! a.Id }" assignTo="{! selectedAccountId }" />
 </apex:commandLink>
```

while your controller would need to declare

```
public Id selectedAccountId { get; set; }
public List<Contact> selectedAccountContacts { get; set; }

public PageReference selectAccount() {
    selectedAccountContacts = [SELECT .... FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :selectedAccountId];
    return null;
}
```

This is just a sketch but hopefully these hints will get you started.

Comment: Thanks! I understand more a bit. I'm wondering now would I put my `outputLink` below the `commandLink` and how can I edit my `pageblockSection` to be displayed next to the `pageBlockTable`?